# Tracking object in online streaming video

Tags: object, video, tracking

Well, i need a software or online services that can choose object in video and tracking it. Object must be highlighted cause in the video a lot of (at least 3) moving objects and a software highlight that object i choose.

Tracking object in the online streaming videos

Comment: **(1)** It's totally not clear why the Google search results are useless to you. Are they not meeting the conditions or requirements that you (never) told us about? Are they not suitable for the footage you (never) showed us? Did they at least detect the specific object that you (never) told us about? I quote again my first comment _"...What was wrong with it?"_.  Knowing these details helps us towards a solution. **(2)** I am not pissed off about your question. It is simply the site rules: [see point **3** about asking for software recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic/).